# How to display special price of product is on special end date of product page in opencart 2.1.0.1?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.1.0.1

Special price of product is not showing on end date which is enter in special tab 
of product in admin section.

Special price is showing only up to one day before of special end date.

SO how can I show special price up to end date & not up to before one day of end date

Answer (score 0):

Opencart store only date of start and end in product_special table. There is no need to require NOW() for validation on it. It's better to use CURDATE() function on that.
Change following code in product.php(controller)

```
ps.date_end > NOW()
```

to

```
ps.date_end >= CURDATE()
```

then it will work. :)